# PHP if statement with isset not working

Tags: php, http-status-code-404

I presumed this was easy code but this doesnt work as intended:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
if (!isset($id)){
    header("HTTP/1.1 404 not found");
    include("404.php");
}
else {
    include('includes/functions.php'); 
}
```

So i've taken the get parameters off of the URL yet i dont receive a 404 error?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You must do the test on `$_GET['id']` directly:

```
if(!isset($_GET['id']) { ... }
```

Even if `$_GET['id']` isn't set, since you tried to assign it to `$id`, `$id` starts to exist, so the test returns true and thus you don't have a 404 error.

Comment: Does `$_GET` work differently compared to other arrays? If an array doesn't have a value for that key you'll get a PHP notice and `$id` will be set to `null`. Therefore `isset($id)` will be `false` in that case and the test should pass. I just tried it and the original code works for me in the PHP 5.3.2 interactive shell.

Comment: No, absolutely not. First of all, isset don't check if the value is null. And second of all, you'll get a notice when accessing an unexisting key only outside of an isset() statement. Actually this is the point of isset, testing if a variable or array element actually exists or not.

Comment: @Krtek - I agree that using the array element directly inside `isset()` is the way to go as it avoids the notice. However, as written the above code works for me. From the [docs for `isset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.isset.php): "Returns TRUE if var exists and has value other than NULL, FALSE otherwise." Perhaps benhowdle89 is passing an empty (`''`) value for the parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You are checking if $id is set. And it is :

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
```

So you must check if the get variable is set:

```
isset($_GET['id'])
```

Answer (score 0):

you have created $id variable in first line. You should check `$_GET['id']`. Also you can check this variable for empty.

Comment: check for emptiness on a non-existing variable can lead to some errors depending on the configuration of the PHP interpreter.

Comment: I mean after checking for existing `if (!isset($_GET['id']) || empty($_GET['id'])) { ... }`